# The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet (google-script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a really very odd problem, which seems to have to do with the sequence i execute scripts. After investigating for hours, I cant explain it at all.

I have a google sheets script which gets emails from an email account and parses them according to given rules into a speadsheets.

I have many of those methods, all leveraging common classes like getEmails, etc.

Every single method of parsing works well and delivers the respected result. But when I run them in a big method one after the other it reports the error

```
"The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet."
```

after executing some of the methods correctly. The error occurs in the following line:

```
var resultArray = sheet.getRange(startrow, column, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
```

and is based on the call

```
sheet.getLastRow()
```

(I can not even call this in the logger, it works for lets say 5 out of the 10 methods and then all the sudden i get the error)

Every of those methods parse a different email with a different pattern but does this only for new emails. Therefore I have to get the hashs of the old emails (thats the call) from the google sheets column 1 to work only on new email hashes. This process breaks somehow.

What is striking me is that i can execute any of the methods isolated without an error.

Any ideas?

As mentioned I have tried isolated and i have tried to change order or to run only 2 of the methods.. with the same result. I assume some variable is not set back properly... but i have no idea how that can lead to this error.

By the way: the code was working for the past few weeks without error (also for the combined method). The errors have started like a week ago without any code changes.

Comment: Try changing `sheet.getLastRow()` to `sheet.getLastRow()+1-startrow`

Comment: As @TheMaster mentions, your math is wrong. Consider the case where `startrow` is 5000 and there are only 5002 total rows of data (`getLastRow()` -> 5002). You're asking for rows 5000 to 10002. Related: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68062620

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughtful feedback. Unfortunately, this is not the case. 

Even the simple call Logger.log("Sheet-NumRow: "+sheet.getLastRow()); fails with the same error, but only (as said) if i run multiple methods at the same time. I am in the right sheet which  Logger.log("Sheet-Name: "+sheet.getName()); shows. 

Additionally, the function you stated is only called with line number 1. 

I really think its a bug in google sheets now.

Comment: We would need to see more code to help with this. Since you only see it occuring when you run the code a certain way, there must be something happening which causes this issue. It is quite unlikely to be a firm bug in Apps Script.  Make a copy of your code and trim it down to the smallest amount of code required to generate the error, so that others can reproduce it and help troubleshoot.  If I had to guess I'm thinking there is an assignment error somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue.

This is a sample of the code that was causing the bug for me:

```js
  var priceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(priceSheetName);
  var rangeToSort = priceSheet.getRange(2,1,priceSheet.getLastRow(),priceSheet.getLastColumn());
  rangeToSort.sort(1);
  ss.getSheetByName("my sheet").getRange(startingRow,pasteColumn,pasteHoldings.length,1).setValues(pasteHoldings);
```

The error `The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet` was raised on line 4 (similar to your scenario), but the issue was occurring when I was trying to sort a range that extended beyond the last row of the sheet i.e.

1. last row with contents = last row of the sheet
2. Sort row start range = 2
3. Number of rows = priceSheet.getLastRow()  *<-- this is impossible because the sort row start range is great than 1*

The fix for me was to adjust the sort range down by the `start row - 1`

```js
  var priceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(priceSheetName);
  var rangeToSort = priceSheet.getRange(2,1,priceSheet.getLastRow()-1,priceSheet.getLastColumn());
  rangeToSort.sort(1);
  ss.getSheetByName("my sheet").getRange(startingRow,pasteColumn,pasteHoldings.length,1).setValues(pasteHoldings);
```

This appears to be a bug in Google Sheets script: either the sort functionality, or at the very least the error handling is raising the error with reference to the wrong row.

My recommendation would be to check your use of `.getLastRow()` and see if it corresponds to a starting row greater than 1. Then adjust the `.getLastRow()` by `starting row - 1`

Answer (score 0):

Would you happen to have your sort range starting on something other than row 1?

I was testing this out and I have my data to sort on A7:N100.

What I found was that the max row that I can have is the last row in the range minus the header rows that are not in the range.  For example, I have the first 6 rows that aren't in the range. I have my last row in row 100.  So my range is only working with A7:N94.

To solve, I ended up adding 6 blank rows to the bottom of my page and set sort range to what I wanted (A7:N100) and this worked.